# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent get distinct with more than 1 column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table which is indexed by id and also has a column description.

I want to use this in a form with it populating a radio group.

My problem is if I try

```
$colours = Colours::where('manufacturer_id',"=",$man)
  ->select('id','description')
  ->orderBy('description')
  ->groupBy('description')
  ->get();
```

I get

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cl24-ids.colours.manufacturer_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `description`, `manufacturer_id` from `colours` where `manufacturer_id` = 1 group by `description`)

Any ideas please or should I just use a non Eloquent solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $colours = Colours::where('manufacturer_id',"=",$man)
                    ->select('id','description')->groupBy('description')->get();
```

Comment: it only makes the key distinct (id) and therefore there is repetition of the colours

Answer (score 7):

The distinct method allows you to fetch the query to return distinct results:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->distinct()->get();
```

Get unique rows

```
$categories = Machine::distinct('category')->pluck('category','antoher');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get distinct data just pass column as array in get method with distinct.

`$myusers = User::distinct()->get(['created_by']);`

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any where in your System jut use code like in laravel

```
\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");//this is the trick use it just before your query

$data=Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 0)->groupBy('task_code')->get(['id','task_code', 'title']);
```