# SQL Laravel 5.7 unique() on collection really slow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to calculate the number of unique records based on a `mobile` column that has an index via the Laravel `collect` and `unique` method. I have 200,000 rows and have a column called `optout_csv_schedule_id` that has an index on it along with the mobile. Right now, it's been running over 15 minutes for the query to execute, how can I improve the performance of this as I need to calculate the number of unique numbers out of the 200,000, my current query is:

```php
/**
 * Get valid lead count
 */
protected function getValidLeadCount($schedule_id)
{
    $optoutConnectionLogs = OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', $schedule_id)
                                               ->get();

    // no leads
    if (!$optoutConnectionLogs) {
        return 0;
    }

    // count total unique leads
    $uniqueLeads = collect($optoutConnectionLogs)->unique('mobile')->count();
    return $uniqueLeads;
}
```

Comment: You are not using the database to do the unique, you already got the records with `->get()`, and are using PHP/Laravel to do it.  [You can try `distinct()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422496/laravel-5-5-eloquent-get-distinct-with-more-than-1-column) to get unique records, or use DB to manually write the SQL.

Comment: I tried `distinct` in Laravel 5.7 I cannot seem to pass a column to the method, so running `distinct` gives me the same count as just doing `count()`

Comment: Your question was about performance, not the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be difficult to calculate the number of unique numbers out of the 200,000 in `Laravel`.
Try to change as follows:

```
protected function getValidLeadCount($schedule_id)
{
    $uniqueLeads = OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', $schedule_id)
                                                 ->distinct('mobile')
                                                 ->count('mobile');
    return $uniqueLeads;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the database to do the unique, you already got the records with `->get()`, and are using PHP/Laravel to do it.  That will be *much* slower than using the database.

Use [`distinct()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements) to get unique records, eg:

```
$optoutConnectionLogs = OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', $schedule_id)
    ->select('mobile')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: I need `OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', '74f3620d-dd51-47ee-8d5d-75213f08043b')->distinct('mobile')->count();` which gives me the same as just doing a simple `count` so not the solution I'm afraid.

Comment: `distinct()` does not take a parameter, you need to select the field.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Running `OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', '74f3620d-dd51-47ee-8d5d-75213f08043b')->select('mobile')->distinct()->count();` gives me the same count as without the select`. Mobile returns a string btw.

Comment: I am a bit confused - your question was about performance.  All the methods you are talking about are expected to give you the same answer, the difference is how you do it, in the DB or with Laravel.  My answer is using the DB, and will be much faster, but it won't change the result.

Comment: Wrappingwhat you've supplied in `collect($optoutConnectionLogs)->count();` was the missing piece of the puzzle here. I thought your supplied answer alone would provide me with what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You read all the data into memory, convert it into PHP objects, and then iterate to count the numbers. The database index you created is not used at all.

Your needs should be simplified into the following code

```php
return OptoutConnectionLog::where('optout_csv_schedule_id', $schedule_id)
                           ->distinct('mobile')
                           ->count();
```